# android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Tags: android

When I create a notification the following error is raised:

> 02-17 19:15:40.459 8869-8869
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: PID: 8869
>                                                                               Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle,
>   iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.baranovgroup.nstyle,
>   com.android.systemui=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle,
>   com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle}
>                                                                               android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from
>   package  Couldn't expand RemoteViews for:
>   StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.xxx.www.musicplayer
>   user=UserHandle{0} id=21 tag=null score=0
>   key=0|com.xxx.www.musicplayer|21|null|10133: Notification(pri=0
>   contentView=com.xxx.www.musicplayer/0x7f04004e vibrate=null
>   sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1526)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Here is my code:

```
private void createNotification(SongDetail detail){
    try {

        String songName = detail.getTitle();
        String authorName = detail.getArtist();
        String albumName = detail.getDisplay_name();
        SongDetail audioInfo = MediaController.getInstance().getPlayingSongDetail();

        RemoteViews simpleContentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.player_small_notification);
        RemoteViews expandedView = null;

        if (supportBigNotifications){

            expandedView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.player_big_notification);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.APPLICATION_CONTEXT, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Constants.OPEN_PLAYER);
        intent.setFlags(32768);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(HomeActivity.APPLICATION_CONTEXT, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentTitle(songName).build();

        notification.contentView = simpleContentView;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
        }

        setListeners(simpleContentView);
        if (supportBigNotifications){

            setListeners(expandedView);
        }

        Bitmap albumArt = audioInfo != null ? audioInfo.getSmallCover(HomeActivity.APPLICATION_CONTEXT) : null;

        if (albumArt != null){

            notification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.player_album_art, albumArt);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                notification.bigContentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.player_album_art, albumArt);
            }

        }else {

            notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.player_album_art, R.drawable.music);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                notification.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.player_album_art, R.drawable.music);
            }
        }

        notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_previous, View.VISIBLE);
        notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_next, View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_previous, View.VISIBLE);
            notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_next, View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (MediaController.getInstance().isAudioPaused()){

            notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_pause, View.GONE);
            notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_play, View.VISIBLE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_pause, View.GONE);
                notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_play, View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }else {

            notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_pause, View.VISIBLE);
            notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_play, View.GONE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_pause, View.VISIBLE);
                notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.player_play, View.GONE);
            }
        }

        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.player_song_name, songName);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.player_author_name, authorName);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            notification.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.player_song_name, songName);
            notification.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.player_author_name, authorName);
        }

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        startForeground(21, notification);

        if (remoteControlClient != null){

            RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor metadataEditor = remoteControlClient.editMetadata(true);
            metadataEditor.putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, authorName);
            metadataEditor.putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, songName);

            if (audioInfo != null && audioInfo.getCover(HomeActivity.APPLICATION_CONTEXT) != null){

                metadataEditor.putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK,
                        audioInfo.getCover(HomeActivity.APPLICATION_CONTEXT));
            }
            metadataEditor.apply();
            audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

        Log.e("create Notification",e.toString());
    }
}
```